# Circumvent problems with banding in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape

I came up with a design as shown in the image below. It consists of multiple rings - each of them has a radial gradient going from black to transparent. Unfortunately there are massive banding issues - best seen on the leftmost page on the image below. This seems to be a [known issue](https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inbox/-/issues/154) in Inkscape.

**Any ideas how I could avoid this problem?**

[image]

Comment: Add noise? Yes it also happens in illustrator.

Comment: It will probably happen with any 8-bit image, or any 8-bit display. Most displays are worst at the lower end of their brightness & image compression makes it worse still. You need to add noise or dither to hide it a bit. (I'll leave it to the pros as to how you achieve that; I don't use Inkscape.)

Comment: Would that mean that the print won't have those issues? This is what I care about the most. Found this YouTube tutorial to mitigate the problem, but still not too happy with the result: https://youtu.be/N2Wy4yojYkg

Comment: Hmmm . . . maybe better to recreate this in raster software to be honest. You can now edit 16bit per channel images in the current version of GIMP which should help reduce banding.  Unfortunately there's no way to eliminate banding in gradients entirely. Adding noise can also help break up banding.

Comment: Print will probably have much mych worse time as it has even less levels than a monitor. Though not so much biased in the dark end. You could probably do this if you work with the printer to make adjustments to the halftone (maybe stochastic, as its the same as adding noise) but i would avoid this if you just send things to print.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the helpful comments!

Comment: Actually, the link to the report ist https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inkscape/-/issues/1591 
(it has been moved away from Inbox, and people continue commenting on the moved issue, not on the closed one)